# Why would I use shared memory and separate processes instead of std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, ipc, shared-memory, stdthread

I was watching a recent lecture series on Operating Systems when the lecturer mentioned `shmget` as an example of interprocess communication. This question is about "shared memory" and relatives to `shmget`.

**What is shared memory?**

According to [this webpage](https://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/shm/what-is-shm.html):

> A shared memory is an extra piece of memory that is attached to some
> address spaces for their owners to use. As a result, all of these
> processes[, parent and child,] share the same memory segment and have
> access to it.

**Compared to threads**

Threads already have shared memory space. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

struct SomeData {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

void PrintC(SomeData* data_ptr) {
    std::cout << (*data_ptr).c << "\n";
}


int main() {

    SomeData data{ 4, -2, 18 };

    std::thread c_printer(PrintC, &data);

    std::cout << data.a << "\n";
    c_printer.join();

    return 0;
}
```

**The Questions**

If the programmers needs shared memory, why would they use separate processes instead of separate threads?

Is shared memory (as created by functions like `shmget`) just a way to implement threads (e.g., `std::thread`)?

Are there C++ standard library functions I should expect to use shared memory under the hood, or is shared memory exclusively for when you `fork` new processes?

Comment: Shared memory and threads are completely separate concepts.

Comment: Shared memory can be used even by completely separate processes that were never `fork`ed from a common parent. It's a pretty different mechanism.

Comment: One reason: It is a lot safer to kill a stuck process than a stuck thread.

Comment: Bugs in separate processes are easier to isolate. For example, you have a rogue pointer in one of the processes smashing memory, it can only smash its own memory and the shared memory. It couldn't smash the state of a completely unrelated object in the other process.

Comment: Shared memory (SM) can also be used between processes on different machines (using abstraction layers). This is very useful in high-performance computing. Virtual machines can also use this to share some address space and isolate some others. Browsers use processes for better stability (see Firefox and Chrome) but they need SM so to share some resources. SM can also be used to easily communicate with devices (though this does not work the same way than between processes). For example, SM can be used to map a virtual address space to the VRAM of GPU avoiding the need for explicit transfers.

Comment: @drescherjm, Threads communicate with each other by means of shared variables and/or shared heap objects. That actually is pretty similar to processes communicating with each other through a shared memory window in their address spaces—more so, if you consider that, at a low level, threads typically share their variables and objects by sharing their entire address space.

Comment: I was mainly talking about this point: ***Is shared memory (as created by functions like shmget) just a way to implement threads (e.g., std::thread)?***

Comment: @drescherjm, That could be an answer, maybe with emphasis on the fact that simply sharing a memory window is not the same thing as sharing variables; and also that threads typically share other, non-memory resources (e.g., sockets)

Answer (score 4):

> Why would I use shared memory and separate processes instead of std::thread?

An advantage of using subprocesses instead of threads is that the memory of separate processes can be encapsulated. This is good for privacy concerns (consider a case where you are handling a web requests that contains private information), and also for correctness concerns since the memory of one process cannot be arbitrarily modified by another. Of course, this benefit is not fully realised for the part of shared memory if you choose to use it. Note that shared memory is not the only form of inter process communication.

Advantages of threads are:

- They can be used through a standard API.
- Their creation has potentially less cost. The difference in cost varies from slight (Linux) to significant (Windows). Although, significance is relative. It won't matter for a long running process that runs constant number of processes.

> Is shared memory (as created by functions like shmget) just a way to implement threads (e.g., std::thread)?

On some systems, this may be true as an implementation detail. But from abstract perspective, these are distinct concepts. There is no concept of "shared memory" or "process" in the C++ language.

Comment: 'There is no concept of "shared memory" or "process" in the C++ language.' Everything you wrote was extremely helpful, but this line was the most clarifying.